# Returning several fields with aggregation

Tags: elasticsearch

I want to make an aggregation of `sum` but also return the "group by" fields.

For example, i want to make a query on a school database, to get the average grade on a specific class and study
in SQL i run:

```
select class, study, examId, avg(grade) 
from grades
group by study, examId
```

and the result is something like:

```
class  | study        | avg(grade)
a1     | gymnastics   | 85
a1     | mathematics  | 87 
a2     | gymnastics   | 85
a2     | mathematics  | 87`
```

so the result contains the group by fields (class and study) and the aggregation result.

I want to make the same query with elastic, and to return all the columns in an aggregation (class, study, avg(grade))

Any idea?
Thanks in advance.
Yuval

Answer (score 1):

You need to use [Sub Aggregation](https://www.elastic.co/blog/intro-to-aggregations-pt-2-sub-aggregations)
Use this query:

```
{
"size": 0,
"aggs": {
  "groupByClass": {
     "terms": {
        "field": "class"
     },
     "aggs": {
        "groupByStudy": {
           "terms": {
              "field": "study"
           },
           "aggs": {
              "averageOfGrades": {
                 "avg": {
                    "field": "grade"
                 }
              }
           }
         }
       }
    }
   }
 }
```

Hope this helps